# Хочу сделать систему строительства как в subnautica, но не знаю как?

Tags: unity3d

в subnautica сделано так, что когда ты ставишь одну часть базы то другую ты можешь поставить только на определённом расстоянии и месте от другой. Хотел бы также сделать в своей игре на unity, но не знаю как. Пробовал через OnTriggerEnter и raycast, но не получилось. Подскажите как можно  сделать также. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6tND51Gx20  вот ссылка на видео с этой системой из subnautica. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вы можете использовать:

```
Vector3(Math.Floor(x/square_size)*square_size, Math.Floor(y/square_size)*square_size, Math.Floor(z/square_size)*square_size)
```

для вычисления правильной позиции, таким образом x, y и z всегда будут делитьcя на square_size. Тоесть длинна, ширина и высота каждой части базы должна быть square_size. А изначальные x, y, z это позиции мыши, куда пользователь пытается поставить базу

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я чучуть дурак и до меня ни что не дошло.  Можно объяснить пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Bashlak если я правильно разобрался в вашем ответе, то вы не поняли вопрос потому, что я плохо объяснил, что мне нужно. Если быть точнее в subnautica реализовано так, если вы ставите какую-то часть базы (например, комнату или коридор) то следующую часть если это коридор можно поставить в 2 определённых места например, слева или справа или по диагонали, а если комнату то только в одно место также не важно слева или справа. Такое чувство, что вместе с объектов спавнятся коллайдеры вокруг базы к которым присоединяются части базы, но вряд ли это коллайдеры. посмотрите это видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7Mqw9W5TUc. В нём я подробней заснял как работает эта система в subnautica. Хотел бы так же реализовать в игре что бы, когда ставишь часть базы то другие части рядом можно ставить в определённые места не важно слева, или справа, или спереди, или сзади.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).